# Reduce Resolution of DDS Images in a Folder

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-compression, roblox, image-optimization

I've recently bought a Chinese Windows tablet for $170; It has an Intel Atom X5 Z8300 CPU, which is the low-end Intel Atom that came out last year. I am able to run most games on Roblox.com, but some are very script-heavy or detailed (such as [Phantom Forces](http://www.roblox.com/games/292439477/Game-of-the-Year-Phantom-Forces-Beta)), and my Chinese tablet isn't able to run them at a desirable frame rate.

My solution is to lower the resolutions of the textures that Roblox fetches. I'd prefer to do this with Python, as I'd be able to make it quick and share my creation with the Roblox community as well.

So here is what I have so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
for file in os.listdir('./'):
    if file.endswith('.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg', '.dds', '.ico', '.gif'):
        im = Image.open(file)
        im = im.resize((im.size[0]/4,im.size[1]/4),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save(file)
```

But I have a few problems:
1) PIL doesn't support DDS images, which is what Roblox uses for most of its textures
2) This does not explore subfolders of the folder I gave it
3) I don't know if the Roblox textures HAVE to be 1024x1024 or if I set it to something like 256x256 it will stretch it, I really don't know.

So how do I manipulate DDS image resolutions in Python?

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't figure out a Python solution, but I found that XnConvert works sorta. It adds weird bars on the right of the image, as shown below, but I'm sure I'll find a fix for this.

[image]

http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/#downloads